# Is it possible to change a localization languages on runtime in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, viewdidload

I have a project that needs to have a toggle localization languages feature so users can change the language on runtime (application running) but I don't know how to implement it.

I can toggle the language in a normal way (after change, refresh by calling ViewDidLoad() again), it works for me but it has a risk because viewDidLoad() has so many task. If I refresh it too much it affects the performance.

ViewController - *Action from button for change.*

```
@IBAction func switchLanguages(_ sender: Any) {
    LanguagesManager.doSwitch(vc: self)
    viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift

Comment: @Teetz Thank you, sir. but this library suggest to use a Notification Center for be a observer. If be like that we have to change all view controller. It take effort so much. Do it has other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to change localization on runtime. 
You can use MCLocalization from github : https://github.com/Baglan/MCLocalization
Just you need to know how to use objective-c library in Swift !